# how to use gprof together with autotools?

Tags: c++, autotools, gprof

I have been writing a small open source software using Auto-tools (C++ is the language), and have generated/installed an executive program. Some monte Carlo integration is used and the code is  slow. I wish to use the gprof to improve and wish to ask how to enable gprof in it? 
I have tried: 
./configure CFLAGS=-pg && make && sudo make install
which does NOT work.

Comment: *How* doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

You want CXXFLAGS, not CFLAGS, since you are using C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have also used the CXXFLAGS=-pg. After configure, make, make install and running the code, one output file called gmon.out is generated but I don't think this is the correct form: http://www.itkp.uni-bonn.de/~weiwang/gmon.out

Comment: I didn't follow the link, but you can use the gprof tool to turn gmon.out into a readable format.

Comment: I have tried: gprof gmon.out 
but got the error: gprof: gmon.out: not in executable format

Comment: @weiwang You must put the executable file name before the gmon file.  `gprof a.out gmon.out`